# Django saving forms to sqlite database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am completely new to django and I am currently working on this program which is already in production.

Now I need to save certain forms to a sqlite database and I've watched some tutorials however I cannot understand how to do this.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
{% block content %}
<!-- Modal -->

         
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0"> Receptas</h5>
                    <span class="d-flex flex-row-reverse"><button class="btn btn-secondary" id="save_recipe_btn" type="button"><i class="bi bi-save"></i></br> Saugoti</button></span>
                  </div>
              
                  <div id="card-base" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{recipe_form.ibu}}
                        {{recipe_form.abv}}
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.name|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.style|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.batch_size|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.boile_time|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.efficiency|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.primary_age|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.secondary_age|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.age|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.pub_date|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">{{recipe_form.notes|as_crispy_field}}</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Now I need to save forms like name, style, batch size and so on. In all the tutorials I watch they do something like doing `method = post` and making the button `type = submit`
However, this whole code looks quite a bit different than what they do in the tutorials and I am unsure whether I still should be saving in the same way or should I do something different here.

Could you please help me get on the right track?

Thank you very much!

Comment: My guess is the confusion is with code like this: `{{recipe_form.name|as_crispy_field}}`.  This is just a way to produce nicer looking input fields using a the popular [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, which will generate the input, supply the name, and set the class to make it look good.  You still need a `<form>` tag, and you still need to manually add a submit button for the form, i.e., `<button type='submit'>`.  And when the form is submitted it can be read by your view by doing `request.POST`.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what was causing the confusion. Thank you so much for the answer!